# Can't parse JSON response in the OutSequence wso2 esb?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

At the start of the Outsequence I am using this:

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/JSON" scope="axis2"/>
```

but still I get the error message Content not allowed in prolog.

If I directly send the response to the client without using any mediators I don't get any error.

Below is the full stack trace:

```
[2015-07-07 12:11:35,747] ERROR - RelayUtils Error while building Passthrough stream
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:154)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createStAXSOAPModelBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:73)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:79)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(OMXMLBuilderFactory.java:196)
        at org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder.processDocument(SOAPBuilder.java:55)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:138)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:107)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:82)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:68)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:268)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:488)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:170)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:225)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Also, could you try with case sensitive "application/json"?

Comment: @Depository added the stack trace in the question.

Comment: @Chamila No using
 <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>   also doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to parse JSON response.

WSO2 ESB version used- 4.8.1

Below is the proxy code.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="JsonProxy" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <log level="full">
                <property name="################ REQUEST ###################" expression="$body"/>
            </log>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri="http://ip.jsontest.com/"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="full">
                <property name="################ RESPONSE###################" expression="$body"/>
            </log>
            <log>
                <property name="::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: JSON :::::::::::::::::::::::::::" expression="json-eval($.)"/>
            </log>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </target>
    <description/>
</proxy>
```

Please cross check that below lines are only uncommented in axis2.xml

```
<messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                          class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>

<messageFormatter contentType="application/json/badgerfish"
                          class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONBadgerfishMessageFormatter"/>

<messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                        class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>

<messageBuilder contentType="application/json/badgerfish"
                        class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONBadgerfishOMBuilder"/>
```

Comment: The problem occurs when at the start there is a JSON response.
The outSequence is unable to parse the response.
What you have done will not give any error.

You can try this service: http://www.jsontest.com/
which gives a JSON response and see whether it works or not....

Comment: I tried it with jsontest.com and working fine. I am able to get JSON response and same is getting in REST client. Please check axis2.xml as well. I am giving you my settings as well.

Comment: I have these lines uncommented along with a few other messageFormatter types...
Do you want me to uncomment ONLY these lines...???

Comment: Please uncomment only these line for contentType="application/json". There will be other messageFormatter for different contentType also.

Comment: can you please post your proxyService code(the one with endpoint:jsontest.com). Still I am unable to get result.